# Override association mapping of a trait property in Doctrine 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

Prerequisites:

- PHP 7.1.8
- Symfony 3.3.9
- Doctrine 2.6.x-dev

I wonder if it's possible to override an `inversedBy` attribute of a property association mapping that's taken from a trait.

An interface that I use as a concrete user entity placeholder:

**ReusableBundle\ModelEntrantInterface.php**

```
interface EntrantInterface
{
    public function getEmail();

    public function getFirstName();

    public function getLastName();
}
```

1. The following architecture works just fine (need to create `User` entity that implements `EntrantInterface` and all other entities that are derived from these abstract classes in `AppBundle`):

**ReusableBundle\Entity\Entry.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Entry
{
    /**
     * @var EntrantInterface
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReusableBundle\Model\EntrantInterface", inversedBy="entries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user;

    // getters/setters...
}
```

**ReusableBundle\Entity\Timestamp.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Timestamp
{
    /**
     * @var EntrantInterface
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReusableBundle\Model\EntrantInterface", inversedBy="timestamps")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user;

    // getters/setters...
}
```

And couple more entities with similar structure that utilize `EntranInterface`

2. And this is what I want to achieve - `UserAwareTrait` to be reusable across several entities:

**ReusableBundle\Entity\Traits\UserAwareTrait.php**

```
trait UserAwareTrait
{
    /**
     * @var EntrantInterface
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReusableBundle\Model\EntrantInterface")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user;

    // getter/setter...
}
```

In Doctrine 2.6 if I would use super class and wanted to override its property I'd do this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AssociationOverride({name="property", inversedBy="entities"})
 * })
 */
abstract class Entity extends SuperEntity
{
    // code...
}
```

But if I want that Entity to use `UserAwareTrait` and override association mapping of a property...

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AssociationOverride({name="user", inversedBy="entries"})
 * })
 */
abstract class Entry
{
    use UserAwareTrait;
    // code...
}
```

... and run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` I see this error in the console:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Invalid field override named 'user' for class 'ReusableBundle\Entity\Entry'.

Is there a workaround that I could follow to achieve the desired result?

1. Use trait to store shared properties
2. Override assotiation mapping or (possibly) attributes mapping in the class that uses that trait

Comment: Well I have a similar implementation but in my case the class that uses the trait is not a `MappedSuperclass`. Did you tried this with deleting the `@ORM\MappedSuperclass` line over your `abstract class Entry` ? And more important: You try to override the a relation without specifing it (in this case `ManyToOne`. Try: `@ORM\AssociationOverrides({ @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="user", manyToMany=@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReusableBundle\Model\EntrantInterface", inversedBy="entities")) })`.

Comment: Also in your last code block it is `inversedBy="entries"` which is the same as the original and in your second last it is `inversedBy="entities"`...

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You should change the access modificator from `protected` to `private`. Don't forget that you will not be able to directly manipulate the private property in a subclass and will need a getter.

The exception appears due to the bug (I believe, or a quirk of the behavior) in the `AnnotationDriver`.

```
foreach ($class->getProperties() as $property) {
    if ($metadata->isMappedSuperclass && ! $property->isPrivate()
        ||
        ...) {
        continue;
    }
```

It skips all non-private properties for `MappedSuperclass` letting them to compose metadata on the subclass parsing. But when it comes to overriding the driver tries to do it at a `MappedSuperclass` level, it doesn't remember that the property was skipped, fails to find it in the metadata and raise an exception.

I made a detailed explanation at [the issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6737). You can find there also the link to the unit tests that highlight the case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to try this in your own code to see, but it **could** be possible.

As an experiment, I overridden a trait in a class, then checked for the trait using `class_uses()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php

```
<?php

trait CanWhatever
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        return 'result!';
    }
}

class X
{
    use CanWhatever;

    public function doStuff()
    {
        return 'overridden!';
    }
}

$x = new X();
echo $x->doStuff();
echo "\n\$x has ";
echo (class_uses($x, 'CanWhatever')) ? 'the trait' : 'no trait';
```

This outputs:

```
overridden! 
$x has the trait
```

Which you can see here https://3v4l.org/Vin2H

However, Doctrine Annotations may still pick up the DocBlock from the trait proper rather than the overridden method, which is why I can't give you a definitive answer. You just need to try it and see!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is not what I need. I don’t want to override a method (I would just define it in each class then and annotate individually, and this exactly what I wish to avoid to do). And there’s nothing to override in the body of methods, those just getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and solve it by override the property it self:

```
use UserAwareTrait;
/**
 * @var EntrantInterface
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReusableBundle\Model\EntrantInterface"inversedBy="entries")
 */
protected $user;
```

Comment: Please read carefully, I want to reuse the trait in multiple entities, therefore there’s no chance to override it in trait, inversedBy must have different values for each entity

Comment: Yes, my answer means to override the trait property in each entity, to set a proper inversed by